# Is it always okay to use variables concurrently in Go?

Tags: json, go

I'm writing a small webserver program, and it does a lot of JSON decoding from POST requests coming in.

Initially I thought that instead of initializing a new `json.Decoder` every time a request comes in, I have it as a global variable that gets called on every time and decodes concurrently with goroutines.

As a newcomer to Go, is this okay? Are there times when I shouldn't be doing this and classes will freak out due to not being thread safe (I guess "goroutine" safe would be better)?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with `json.Decoder` -- how would you re-use one as there's no way to change their io.Reader? But no, mostly you can't use go objects concurrently unless they're documented to be safe to use concurrently.

Comment: Ah fair enough, I didn't even think that far ahead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Go, json.NewDecoder takes an io.Reader as an input parameter and returns a *json.Decoder. Hence it is not possible to reuse the same Decoder since we have a different http.Request.Body (which implements io.Reader) for each POST request.

And as mentioned by [Paul Hankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400793/paul-hankin), you can't use go objects concurrently unless they're documented to be safe to use concurrently.

Examples :

> 1. http.Client & http.Transport
>
>    Clients and Transports are safe for
>      concurrent use by multiple goroutines and for efficiency should only
>      be created once and re-used.

[Source](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/)

> 2. Maps
>
>    After long discussion it was decided that the typical use of maps did not require safe access from multiple goroutines.

[Source](http://golang.org/doc/faq#atomic_maps)

If you asked about reusing JSON decoder to avoid the duplication of code you could look at frameworks like [Tigertonic](https://github.com/rcrowley/go-tigertonic) and [Go-Json-Rest](https://github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest).

On a side note you could look at [ffjson](https://github.com/pquerna/ffjson) to speed up JSON Decoding.

Answer (score 2):

Like John and Paul said, this won't do what you expect it to.

If your main concern is code duplication, what you probably want is a middleware. Here is an example of how you could do it

```
type JSONHandler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, *json.Decoder)

func JSONMiddleware(handler JSONHandler) http.HandlerFunc{
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
        handler(w, req, decoder)
    }
}

func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, decoder *json.Decoder) {
    // Put your code here, you have access to the decoder
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/myroute", JSONMiddleware(MyHandler))
    ...
}
```

(on playground: https://play.golang.org/p/4ZTaQguNj7)